# Making sure Http-Requests are executed when Angular-PWA is opened

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I need to make an http-request when my Progressive-Web-App is openend. This works fine when the user closes the app. But when it is still in memory and opened (e.g. the next day), than my http-request is not executed.

The Request is placed in ngOnInit().

Is there any lifecycle method that guarantees it is executed when the component comes to the foreground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to making the requests in the `ngOnInit()` function, listen for changes to the page visibility, and make the request once the page becomes visible again.

```js
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    console.log('Page visible, make HTTP requests!');
  }
});
```

The [Page Lifecycle API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api) does cover some of this, but there isn't a single event that will fire both on page load, and when the page becomes visible again.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a difference between document.addEventListener(...) and @HostListener('window:focus', ['$event'])?

Comment: @prosk - I don't know the answer to that, I'd suggest asking it as a separate question. Sorry!